# Exception shown while redirecting to the login page in Blazor Server

Tags: blazor

I have created a Blazor Server project in .NET 6. I want to implement my own custom authentication in this project. So I have created a login component under **Page** folder. And I have configured my App.razor file below so that while not authenticated it redirects to the login page.

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeView>
                <Authorized>
                    <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
                    <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
                </Authorized>
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <LoginRedirect></LoginRedirect>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeView>
        </Found>   
        
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <AuthorizeView>
                <Authorized>
                    <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                        <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
                    </LayoutView>
                </Authorized>
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <LoginRedirect></LoginRedirect>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Here is my **LoginRedirect** component code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace BlazorJwtToken.Shared
{
    public partial class LoginRedirect
    {
        [Inject] NavigationManager? NavigationManager { get; set; }
        protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            var returnUrl = "/" + NavigationManager?.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri);
            
            NavigationManager?.NavigateTo($"/login?returnUrl={returnUrl}", false);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the project it hits the **OnInitializedAsync** function of LoginRedirect component and throws the below exception:

[image]

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to solve the problem.

Comment: I have just tested this and it works in my test environment.  There must be something you're not including in the question that is causing the problem.   What is `Login`?   Question: If your login "page" is a Blazor component then why not just load the login component when Not Authorized?

Comment: Maybe try remove the slash at the start of return url? `var returnUrl = "/" + ...`

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Login is a Blazor component under the Page folder. I tried to load the login page when not authorized through the LoginRedirect component. You can see it in the app.component file

Comment: What I meant was replace <LoginRedirect />  with <Login /> i.e. the component itself.