# Too many redirects problem error while redirecting to the login page in Blazor server

Tags: blazor

I have created a Blazor Server project in .NET 6. I want to implement my own custom authentication in this project. So I have created a login component under Page/Account folder. In that account folder there is a new Layout page. And I have configured my App.razor file below so that while not authenticated it redirects to the login page.

```xml
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
  <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">

    <Found Context="routeData">
      <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>
          <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
          <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
          <LoginRedirect></LoginRedirect>
        </NotAuthorized>
      </AuthorizeView>
    </Found>

    <NotFound>
      <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
      <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>
          <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
          </LayoutView>
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
          <LoginRedirect></LoginRedirect>
        </NotAuthorized>
      </AuthorizeView>
    </NotFound>

  </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Here is my LoginRedirect component code:

```cs
public partial class LoginRedirect
{
    [Inject] NavigationManager? NavigationManager { get; set; }
    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var returnUrl = NavigationManager?.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri);
        
        NavigationManager?.NavigateTo($"/account/login/{returnUrl}", false);

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

When I am running the project I get the below error:

[image]

I have uploaded the project in github. **Here is the github [link](https://github.com/mnu-nasir/BlazorJwtToken)** . Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue in your `LoginRedirect`, you are wrongly using `returnUrl`. You are not giving it as an HTTP argument but as path. I believe then that you end up in a `NotFound` and `NotAuthorized` situation and loop infinitely by adding more to the path over and over.

```
NavigationManager?.NavigateTo($"/account/login/{returnUrl}", false);
```

should be something like this:

```
NavigationManager?.NavigateTo($"/account/login?returnUrl={returnUrl}", false);
```

Comment: It's not working. I have uploaded the project into github, you can try your code there.

Comment: I believe you have a second issue: your App.razor code also applies to your Login page. Since you are not connected when accessing the Login page, it gets redirected to itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to both this question and your previous one, and the comments you provided there:

[Exception shown while redirecting to the login page in Blazor Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73505868/exception-shown-while-redirecting-to-the-login-page-in-blazor-server)

I think you can simplify how you handle the login.  You don't need to redirect at all, just build your login into `App`.  Here's a very basic login system I use for testing that demostrates how to incorporate the login component into App.  There's no need to capture which page the user is trying to access.  The user is already on it.

There's quite a bit of code here as it's a working demo.  Starting template is the Blazor Server template.

First classes to provide some test identities:

```
public static class TestIdentityProvider
{
    public const string Provider = "Dumb Provider";

    public static ClaimsIdentity GetIdentity(string userName)
    {
        var identity = identities.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name.Equals(userName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        if (identity == null)
            return new ClaimsIdentity();

        return new ClaimsIdentity(identity.Claims, Provider);
    }

    private static List<TestIdentity> identities = new List<TestIdentity>()
        {
            VisitorIdentity, 
            UserIdentity, 
            AdminIdentity, 
        };

    public static List<string> GetTestIdentities()
    {
        var list = new List<string> { "None" };
        list.AddRange(identities.Select(identity => identity.Name!).ToList());
        return list;
    }

    public static Dictionary<Guid, string> TestIdentitiesDictionary()
    {
        var list = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();
        identities.ForEach(identity => list.Add(identity.Id, identity.Name));
        return list;
    }

    public static TestIdentity UserIdentity
        => new TestIdentity
        {
            Id = new Guid("10000000-0000-0000-0000-100000000001"),
            Name = "User",
            Role = "UserRole"
        };

    public static TestIdentity VisitorIdentity
        => new TestIdentity
        {
            Id = new Guid("10000000-0000-0000-0000-200000000001"),
            Name = "Visitor",
            Role = "VisitorRole"
        };

    public static TestIdentity AdminIdentity
        => new TestIdentity
        {
            Id = new Guid("10000000-0000-0000-0000-300000000001"),
            Name = "Admin",
            Role = "AdminRole"
        };
}
```

```cs
public record TestIdentity
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;

    public string Role { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public Claim[] Claims
        => new[]{
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, this.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, this.Name),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, this.Role)
    };

}
```

And a very basic `AuthenticationStateProvider`:

```cs
public class SimpleAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    ClaimsPrincipal? _user;

    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        => Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_user ?? new ClaimsPrincipal()));

    public Task<AuthenticationState> ChangeIdentityAsync(string username)
    {
        _user = new ClaimsPrincipal(TestIdentityProvider.GetIdentity(username));
        var task = this.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        this.NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(task);
        return task;
    }
}
```

The `Login` component:

```cs
@implements IDisposable

@using System.Security.Claims;

<span class="me-2">Change User:</span>
<div class="w-25">
    <select id="userselect" class="form-control" @onchange="ChangeUser">
        @foreach (var value in TestIdentityProvider.GetTestIdentities())
        {
            @if (value == _currentUserName)
            {
                <option value="@value" selected>@value</option>
            }
            else
            {
                <option value="@value">@value</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private Task<AuthenticationState> AuthTask { get; set; } = default!;

    [Inject] private AuthenticationStateProvider authState { get; set; } = default!;
    private SimpleAuthenticationStateProvider AuthState => (SimpleAuthenticationStateProvider)authState!;

    private ClaimsPrincipal user = new ClaimsPrincipal();
    private string _currentUserName = "None";

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (AuthTask is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("There's no cascaded Task<AuthenticationState> provided!");

        var authState = await AuthTask;
        this.user = authState.User;
        AuthState.AuthenticationStateChanged += this.OnUserChanged;
    }

    private async Task ChangeUser(ChangeEventArgs e)
        => await AuthState.ChangeIdentityAsync(e.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty);

    private async void OnUserChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> state)
        => await this.GetUser(state);

    private async Task GetUser(Task<AuthenticationState> state)
    {
        var authState = await state;
        this.user = authState.User;
    }

    public void Dispose()
        => AuthState.AuthenticationStateChanged -= this.OnUserChanged;
}
```

And modified `LoginDisplay`:

```cs
<AuthorizeView>
    <span class="me-2">Hello, @(context.User.Identity?.Name!)</span><button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.LogOut>Log Out</button>
</AuthorizeView>

@code {
    [Inject] private AuthenticationStateProvider? authState { get; set; }

    private SimpleAuthenticationStateProvider AuthState => (SimpleAuthenticationStateProvider)authState!;

    private async Task LogOut(MouseEventArgs e)
        => await AuthState.ChangeIdentityAsync(string.Empty);
}
```

The registered services:

```cs
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, SimpleAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
```

And `App`:

```cs
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <Authorizing><h3>Trying to authorize you.</h3></Authorizing>
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <h3>Sorry mate, you can't go here now!</h3>
                    <Login />
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Finally add to `Index`:

```cs
@attribute [Authorize()]
```

and `Counter` anbd `FetchData`:

```cs
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "AdminRole, UserRole")]
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens. The `OnInitializedAsync` method on your `LoginRedirect` class throws an exception on the `NavigationManager?.NavigateTo`. Since you're recording the base path to a variable and appending it to your `NavigationManager?.NavigateTo`, the URL in your screenshot looks repeating.

This behavior happens if your render mode is `ServerPrerendered`. Disable the pre-render by going to `_Host.cshtml` and update the `render-mode` from `ServerPreRendered` to `Server`.

`<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />`